# Issues with code behind generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

For some odd reason, I can't get my page's code behind to generate, the file has been created but none of the controls seem to be getting generated in..

There are no warnings/errors coming from VS when I am trying to generate this file, this has worked in the past but suddenly it stopped working and as far as I know nothing has changed apart from I have installed .NET Demon which I have tried disabling fully but this doesn't appear to change it.

I have spent a good few hours looking into this issue and all I have found in terms of solutions is to delete the .designer.cs file and then converting the .aspx file to a web application but this does not fix my issue. I have also tried to recreate the page but no luck either, I will put below a few bits of code that may help.

Generated file namespace:

`namespace Web.admin.reports {`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Web.admin.reports.productpromotionsummary" Title="Promotions Summary" CodeBehind="~/admin/reports/productpromotionsummary.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" %
```

If you need anymore information please feel free to ask

Comment: What is exactly the behavior of Visual Studio? Do you get any error / warning in the visual studio error window?

Comment: Apologies, I should have put this in my OP, I'll update it now.. But no, there is no error.

Comment: Out of curiosity is it only for this specific page or does it repeat this behavior if you try to create another page (by another name) and its code behind?

Comment: It appears that it is all pages.

Comment: When you say that none of the controls appear to be 'generated in', what do you mean? If you put on a control on the code-in-front (never liked that name) then it doesn't mean anything should appear in the code-behind. If, however, you mean that you can't reference anything on the page from the code-behind then that's a different thing.

Comment: The definitions in the designer.cs that should be getting generated to allow me to access them in the code behind isn't being generated

Comment: But can you manually generate the references and they link up correctly to your page?

Comment: No, I can not for some reason.